# Printing using DLL File to Multiple Printers from Server Local TCP/IP Printer

Tags: printing, asp-classic, iis-6, iis-8

**Background Information:**

Trying to Migrate the Web Site from Server 2003 to 2012 R2

Office 32bit is installed

Local Printers were set up to Mirror the old version (64bit Drivers with 86bit installed)

Code:

```
Set xx = server.createobject("Maintenance.Request")
z = xx.PrintRequest(dbMaintPath,TheID)
Set xx = nothing

If z = 0 then                    *Line 88*
```

Error message when trying to print using the form and Access Database; The data is written to the Database

```
MaintPrint.dll is Regsvr32

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: '[string: "482 Printer error"]'

/forms/MaintRequest/submit2.asp, line 88
```

I have tried to create and Server 2012 with .NET 1.1 and still received the same error

Comment: What do this object `Maintenance.Request`?

This line `z = xx.PrintRequest(dbMaintPath,TheID)` doesn't return an integer, it return the error message `482 Printer error`.  You have to fix the method `PrintRequest()` first.

Comment: But, what does PrintRequest?  Do you have source code of that dll?

Comment: Maintenance.Request seems to point to the Registry at two locations. dbMaintPath points to forms.asp under inc which is referenced in the code at the top and TheID is the number which was updated in the access database.   This Code works fine within Server 2003 however i am not sure why it doesn't on 2012 or 2012 R2

Comment: This code was created in 2002 and the person that created it wants to charge 500$ per hour since he doesn't want to deal with it. I don't know where the source of the MaintPrint.dll.

Comment: I was able to open the DLL using Visual Studio 2008.   Library Maintenance
Class Request
Function PrinterList() As Variant
Function PrintRequest(varDB, varRequest) As Variant

Comment: But server 2003 and 2012 are not the same!  By default, on Windows Server 2012, the profile (which run your IIS) is loaded with minimum data.  I'm not surprised this doesn't works.  I'm not sure what is the quickest way to solve this.  A good way is to create a new service, in asp.net Web api 2, or asp.net core, and you call it from asp classic.  This will give you maximum flexibility and you can maintain your new code.

Comment: DanB, Do you have any atricles on how to do this?  I haven't done that before.

Comment: Before doing this, did you tried to decompile your dll?  If your are lucky, you can see source code and fix it.  It you cannot, see this : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis

Comment: Seems to be an Native DLL due to is not a .NET module from Reflector and not supported using dotPeek (dotpeek provides metadata)